# Smooth Scroll Down whilst slideDown

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, slide

How can I make the page smoothly scroll down a specified amount at the same time as the slideDown? e.g. 75% or 750px

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#block-full-content-thumb-1").click(function(){
    $("#panel-1").slideDown("slow");
  });
});
```

Comment: Provide JSFiddle please.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#block-full-content-thumb-1").click(function(){
    $("#panel-1").slideDown("slow");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#block-full-content-thumb-1').click(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#portfolio-sep').offset().top
        }, 'slow');
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#panel-close").click(function(){
    $("#panel-1").slideUp("slow");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#panel-close').click(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#portfolio-top').offset().top
        }, 'slow');
    });
});
```